# Windows Domain Authentication with Firefox

Tags: firefox, internet-explorer, domain, authentication

We have many internal web sites on our domain:

- a.blah.com
- b.bhah.com
- c.blah.com

IE authenticates automatically using the currently signed in domain user but fire fox pops up a login box, sometimes multiple times per page load if assets on different internal sites are referenced.  I've tried modifying about:config as suggest by this [post](http://codebetter.com/blogs/eric.wise/archive/2006/11/16/Note-to-self_3A00_-Firefox-Windows-Authentication.aspx) but that didn't resolve the issue.

Does anyone have any other suggestions about how to get firefox to authenticate using the signed in domain user?  I'm currently using the [IETab](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1419) firefox addon to load these internal pages using the IE engine but I'd prefer a simpler solution...

Comment: Firefox can apparently do the authentication, but I've never been able to get it to work so I just use IETab too.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think this will cover you:

http://markmonica.com/2007/11/20/firefox-and-integrated-windows-authentication/

How to configure Firefox

1. Open Firefox
2. In the address bar type: about:config
3. Firefox3.x and later requires you to agree that you will proceed with caution.
4. After the config page loads, in the filter box type: network.automatic
5. - Modify network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris by double clicking the row and enter http://www.replacewithyoursite.com
6. - Multiple sites can be added by comma delimiting them such as http://www.replacewithyoursite.com, http://www.replacewithyourintranetsite.com

Answer (score 5):

If you are on a network using Kerberos for authentication, you should try the following.

Open about:config in Firefox and navigate via the filter 'network.negotiate-auth'. You will see a handful of settings related to Kerberos / GSSAPI Authentication.

The two of interest will be 'network.negotiate-auth.delegation-uris' and 'network.negotiate-auth.trusted-uris'. It sounds like all of the sites where you need to authenticate are under one domain, so the following settings should work for you.

network.negotiate-auth.delegation-uris => http://
network.negotiate-auth.trusted-uris => blah.com

If you need to set multiple sites/domains, then you would modify the latter to be the following.

network.negotiate-auth.trusted-uris => a.blah.com,b.blah.com,c.blah.com

One caveat that you should beware is the delegation uri should ideally be using https instead of http. If you are in a closed private network this typically not a big deal, but you'll be opening yourself up to man-in-the-middle exploits against sites that are accessed over the internet. If you want both allowed, you can use the following.

network.negotiate-auth.delegation-uris => http://,https://

Regarding the comment by brendan, the values for network.negotiate-auth.trusted-uris are the same as you would set for network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris to enable NTLM. On most servers using windows 2003 or later; you will see that Negotiate is attempted before NTLM.

Answer (score -1):

If you're not logged in as the Windows domain user, Firefox has no way to set a generic login for, say, `*.blah.com`.

Tracked as Mozilla [Bug 589628](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=589628).