# Does Firefox support wildcards in NTLM / Negotiate URI's for autologin?

Tags: firefox, authentication, ntlm, kerberos

Following this question about [**Windows Domain Authentication with Firefox**](https://superuser.com/questions/5161/windows-domain-authentication-with-firefox), does FF support using wildcards in the URI's?  I'm not finding anything where it mentions support either way.

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes, I have....

Comment: So that means it doesn't work then? Or does it?

Comment: Sorry, thought that would be clear since I'm asking.  No, my efforts didn't work.  I was looking around to find out if FF just simply does not support it or if maybe my wildcard syntax was just wrong.

Comment: I was interested in this because I wanted to support any port on localhost.  As it turns out, just `http://localhost` works fine.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Just to expand on redbeard0x0a's answer, it seems that it's matching based on the end of the string, not a sub string. So, if you have a company domain like "mycompany.com" with servers like svn.mycompany.com, sharepoint.mycompany.com, mail.mycompany.com, you could modify the `network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris` within about:config to:

> `svn.mycompany.com,sharepoint.mycompany.com,mail.mycompany.com`

or just include them all and any other internal servers by doing:

> `mycompany.com`

Comment: Note that you need at least on dot for it to be a wildcard. So if you can host1.hr.europe.company1.  Then company1 will not work, you need to put europe.company1.  I guess if there is no dot firefox assumes it's a hostname not a domain name.

Comment: I think you'll want to use ".mycompany.com", leaving that leading dot out would match "notmycompany.com".

Comment: @David @davenpcj I wish I could use example.*, i.e. example.com, example.net, etc

Comment: Just to add to this, I found that `mycompany.com` had to be at the end of the list if I had any more specific entries.  For example `http://localhost,.mycompany.com` worked, but `.mycompany.com,http://localhost` did *not* work.  Mine is now working fine, but I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if I understand the question correctly, but I'm thinking you are trying to use a wildcard in the network.authentication-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris inside firefox's config.

I think everything is matched on a sub-string (internally it seems to work like `*example.local*`, so having the domain `example.local` you would put `example.local` in the configuration, for example: `localhost,fileserver,example.local`.

If you end up having a url of `http://server1.example.local/`, it should trigger the `example.local` entry for trusted-uris and seamlessly send over NTLM authentication.